# How to read newline character with Java ReadFile's read

Tags: java, io, filereader

I have a simple question about Java class Reader's `read()` method.

The documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)

> Reads a single character. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

So I am trying to convert a file `message.txt` to a string and thought `read` would work well since it faithfully gets every character. My txt file has a newline followed by a message.

`message`

I set up this code to read every character including the initial new line.

```
private static String readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException{
    FileReader r = new FileReader(file);
    String str="";
    int ch;
    while ((ch=r.read())!=-1)
    {
        System.out.println((char)ch);
        str+=(char)ch;
    }
    return str;
}
```

However, I get an extra character (presumably from the newline) in the output like below. Would really help if someone could clue me into this behavior of Reader and what I should do to make it add a special character.

```
print char

print char

print char m

print char e

print char s

print char s

print char a

print char g

print char e
```

Comment: Some OS like Windows separate lines using `\r` `\n` so these are two characters.

Comment: Isn't your `newline character` in the beginning actually a sequence of `\r` and `\n` like it would be on Windows?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove or filter the newline character out?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why dont you use readLine() instead? You won't have to bother with new lines

Comment: You should print the numerical value, too. So we can see what these non printable characters are.

Comment: Thanks I did that. It turned out to be carriage return and new line like the others said

Answer (score 0):

That extra space is because you are using "println". So whenever it reads a newline character in the file it prints a new line and the "println" is adding one extra line to it.
Instead of "println", try "print".

Comment: I tried that, but am still getting the same result.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input data from your file?

Comment: The program is reading the new line as two special characters as others above mentioned: `\r\n`, which explains the extra `print char`